# Java Servlet - ERROR 404 Recurso requerido no encontrado - No encuentro el error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tomcat

Tengo una aplicación web en JSP. Hice un cambio de computadora y migré mi proyecto de eclipse a la nueva computadora. En la antigua tenía Tomcat 9, ahora cuento con Tomcat 10.
No hice ningún cambio en el código cuando mandé todo a la nueva computadora.

Al momento de correr mi aplicación y buscar el primer servlet, no lo encuentra, me manda error:

***Estado HTTP 404 – No encontrado 

Tipo Informe de estado

mensaje El recurso requerido [/ProyectoWeb/LoginServlet] no se encuentra disponible

Descripción El recurso requerido no está disponible.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.2***

Cabe mencionar que no uso el descriptor de implementación, uso los annotations con el @WebServlet

```
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
* Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
*/
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
...contenido de mi clase...
}
```

Reescribí una parte de la aplicación en otro proyecto de prueba porque pensé que tal vez algo cambiaría entre la versión 9 y la 10 de Tomcat, sin embargo el resultado es el mismo.
Aunque parece que le tengo que definir de dónde va a tomar los servlets por default al usar un annotation, no estoy seguro en dónde pueda configurar eso.

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar o guiar con este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que javax.* ya no funciona, ahora es Jakarta.*
La documentación se encuentra en el siguiente link:
http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html#Migrating_from_9.0.x_to_10.0.x

Reemplazar todos mis imports de "javax." a "jakarta." fue la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien lo solucione cambiando todos mis imports de "javax." a "jakarta."
ya que tenia configurado con la libreria "java EE Web 8 Api"