# Java Servlet - ERROR 404 en archivo JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

En una aplicación web en JSP he estado llamando a un servlet para exportar a un xml pero hoy a decidido no funcionar.

Este es el codigo del boton que redirecciona al servlet:

```
<button onclick="location.href='/ExportAnimalesXmlServlet'"
    style="border: 2px solid #000; padding: 5px 10px; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; margin: 4px 2px; cursor: pointer; color: green;">Exportar
    a XML</button>
```

Este es el servlet al que redirecciona:

```
package com.zoologico.servlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

@WebServlet("/ExportAnimalesXmlServlet")

public class ExportAnimalesXmlServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Y por ultimo este es el codigo de mi web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <!-- Configuración de las etiquetas JSTL -->
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-impl.jar</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ExportAnimalesXmlServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.zoologico.servlet.ExportAnimalesXmlServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ExportAnimalesXmlServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ExportAnimalesXmlServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Estoy usando Tomcat 9 en Eclipse

Lo he estado repasando y no encuentro el error

P.D he intentado arreglarlo usando esta otra [duda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432070/java-servlet-error-404-recurso-requerido-no-encontrado-no-encuentro-el-error) pero eso es para cuando migras de Tomcat 9 a 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error resulto. Era una tonteria pero que molesta bastante.

Al crear el servidor se pone el nombre del Proyecto por defecto, en mi caso "Proyecto_conjunto_1º_CFGS", y lo cambie a "Proyecto" y especifique en los servlts que la ruta era "/Proyecto/(nombre servlet)". Al borrar el servidor y crear oto nuevo esta configuración se perdio por lo que todo estaba mal.

Para arreglarlo siguan lo siguiente (en Eclipse):

- Ve a la vista de `Servers`.
- Haz clic derecho en el servidor Tomcat y selecciona `Open`.
- En la configuración del servidor, verás una sección llamada `Modules`. Aquí deberías ver tu proyecto y la ruta (path) asociada a él.
- Haz clic en `Edit...` y cambia la ruta a `/(nombre deseado)`